# Cant view downloaded file in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, user-data, iaas

Im trying to download a file using wget using Cloudformation. However, I dont see the file in the directory I downloaded it to ( /home/ubuntu/). Ive also tried different things like creating directories in /home/ubuntu but I also dont see the created directory

The following is the portition of the cloudformation code I am having trouble with. Lets assume that I am calling these commands correctly with cfn-init. I see the user data execute the cfn-init command but I dont see the files.

I wget the file and put it into /home/ubuntu/odbc_connector.tar.gz. When I go onto the server I do not find the file.

```
Instance:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        Metadata:
          AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            configSets:
              Instance_install:
                # Install ODBC connector / pyodbc
                - setup_pyodbc
            setup_pyodbc:
              commands:
                # Install ODBC connector
                download_connector:
                    command: wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.19-linux-ubuntu18.04-x86-64bit.tar.gz -O /home/ubuntu/odbc_connector.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `wget` command should be:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.19-linux-ubuntu18.04-x86-64bit.tar.gz  -O /home/ubuntu/odbc_connector.tar.gz
```

There may be other issues, that fail in your template, but you should still correct your wget command.

Comment: Yes, good point. I did change it to this, I still see no file in my /home/ubuntu directory

Comment: I moved the wget command to my user-data instead and it worked fine. The question now is, not sure why this command works when I run this in user-data but not when I run this in MetaData.

Comment: @vi_ral What is your user-data? Are you calling correctly  `cfn-init` command correctly there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to debug the issue. You'll have to go into the instance =>

`cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`  - to check cf error
`cat /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001`  - to view script

The cloud-init-output.log should tell you why the command didn't run